# Azure DevOps Pipeline Flutter Install task error

Tags: azure, flutter, azure-devops-pipelines

i'm trying to create a build pipeline for my flutter app using azure devops.

I use the azure extension for flutter from  visual studio market. The flutter install task fail with error

```
##[error]Error: The process '/usr/bin/unzip' failed with exit code 9
```

I trayed all Flutter extensions I got same error,
My steps 
Create pipeline 
add Flutter Install  
Accept default two options , stable and latest 
save 
run

got same error each time !

Comment: Just by web searching, it seems that this error can occur when the target of the unzip command is not present. Did a source code download, or similar, fail, in the run of your pipeline?

Comment: Thnx for your response, No I didn't download or mentioned any paths. If you have a guide to deploy the flutter app step by step in Azure DevOps , or tell me which step I have to do before Flutter Install

Comment: All existing tasks as following    ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gD_7gFUHGVPMR58U6BpM9TCu_9m7QMyO/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Current Pipeline as following ![Valid XHTML](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10yCX5SYSp5xDGk1c9W4wrnDvxohLFRNo/view?usp=sharing).